# Calculating image pixel values (e.g. the mean) of Contour-inliers using mask & ROI in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

**The problem**
I want to calculate the mean value of the pixel values belonging to a contour given as a vector of Points in OpenCV. The image is rather big compared to the contour, so I would like to first set a ROI as big as the bounding box of the contour and do the masking afterwards. However, this does not really work and I get zeros as result for mean calculation.

**The code with line numbers**

```
1)  Mat crop = Mat(*img, bounding_box); //img is the original image (may be 1024*1024)  
2)  Mat mask = Mat::zeros(crop.rows, crop.cols, CV_8UC1); //the mask with the size of cropped image  
3)  vector<vector<Point> > contours;  
4)  contours.push_back(*cv_contour);   
5)  drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, CV_AA, noArray(), 1, bounding_box.tl());   
6)  double mean_ = sum(mean(crop, mask))[0]; // returns wrong results (0)
```

Btw: Is there a way to avoid the creation of a new array (line 3&4) for `drawContours` if I only want to draw ONE contour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your error is in the algebraic sign in the offset for drawContours. Let me show you, what I mean with this example code that produces the following output: http://daiw.de/share/Forum/stackoverflow_calculating-image-pixel-values-e-g-the-mean-of-contour-inliers-using-mask-r_001.png

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    // Create a small image with a circle in it.
    cv::Mat image(256, 256, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    cv::circle(image, cv::Point(80, 110), 42, cv::Scalar(255, 127, 63), -1);

    // Create random Contour
    typedef cv::vector<cv::Point> TContour;
    TContour contour;
    contour.push_back(cv::Point(20, 30));
    contour.push_back(cv::Point(40, 110));
    contour.push_back(cv::Point(140, 140));
    contour.push_back(cv::Point(160, 50));

    // The conversion to cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point>> is unavoidable,
    // but can easily be achieved with a temporary instance.
    cv::Mat imageWithContour(image.clone());
    typedef cv::vector<TContour> TContours;
    cv::drawContours(imageWithContour, TContours(1, contour), -1, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    // Show the contour.
    cv::imshow("image with contour", imageWithContour);

    // Get ROI image.
    cv::Rect roi(cv::boundingRect(contour));
    cv::Mat crop(image, roi);

    // Calculate ROI mean.
    cv::Mat mask(cv::Mat::zeros(crop.rows, crop.cols, CV_8UC1)); //the mask with the size of cropped image
    // The offset for drawContours has to be *minus* roi.tl();
    cv::drawContours(mask, TContours(1, contour), -1, cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, CV_AA, cv::noArray(), 1, -roi.tl());
    //auto mean(cv::sum(cv::mean(crop, mask)));
    auto mean(cv::mean(crop, mask));
    auto sum(cv::sum(mean));

    // Show crop and mask.
    cv::imshow("crop", crop);
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);

    // Print mean.
    std::cout << "mean: " << mean[0] << ", " << mean[1] << ", " << mean[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sum: " << sum[0] << std::endl;

    // Wait for user input.
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Generally it is a good idea to just see the intermediate steps visually when working with images.

Comment: Yap, that was indeed the problem. Just the sign in front of the .tl(). Thanks a lot!